# Microservice with auth as separate service

Tags: microservices

Is it a best practice to have auth as a separate service in micro-service architecture application?

I saw in some microservices app, the authentication is part of each micro-services as inbuilt.

Comment: `Authenticate` by separate service make more sense. Where did you saw this "the authentication is part of each micro-services as inbuilt" ?

Comment: @ray please read this link in detail - https://dzone.com/articles/authentication-and-authorization-in-microservices

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you'd usually want to authenticate in a separate service (many times this can be an external service). besides the obvious reason of duplication the more important reason for that is security.

Getting authentication right can be a challenge  (just search for oauth, openId and/or SAML) not to mention registration flows for new users, revoking access etc.

Comment: So the goal in having microservice here is to DRY the auth frontend.

Comment: it is to get security right - and having a minimal number of  components  that specialize around that  makes that easier

Comment: But just for that you could just put it in a "common library" as a single "component" sourced by each service. With the same number of library API calls as when it is a separate web service with HTTP API.

Comment: and update all your services each time there's  something to change there? why do you create services in the first place?    flexibility and  encapsulation and independent dev/rollout

Comment: So it is to DRY the frontend deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific. Hence, generally speaking, the short answer is yes.

One of the principles you should follow when implementing a microservices architecture is to avoid duplication of responsibilities, specially on a functional level.

Authentication is no exception to this. On the contrary, it's a critical function that you typically want to centralize. There are different patterns that can help with ensuring that authentication and authorization are implemented in a consistent way across all services, most commonly using an API gateway.